# Set up emotion babel plugin with NextJS?

Tags: babeljs, next.js, emotion

I'm trying to set up the emotion babel plugin with NextJS.

Ive created a new NextJS project. Then installed `@emotion/core` and `babel-plugin-emotion`

In package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/core": "^10.0.15",
    "babel-plugin-emotion": "^10.0.15",
```

Ive created a .babelrc file in my project root with this:

```
{
  "presets": ["next/babel"],
  "plugins": ["emotion"]
}
```

If I use emotion in the standard way it works:

```
import React from "react";
/** @jsx jsx */
import { css, jsx } from "@emotion/core";

const style = css`
  opacity: 0.4;
  background: gold;
`;

function Component({ number }) {
  return (
    <div css={style} />
  );
}
```

I thought that the babel plugin allowed me to use this cleaner syntax:

```
import React from "react";
import { css } from "@emotion/core";

const style = css`
  opacity: 0.4;
  background: gold;
`;

function Component({ number }) {
  return (
    <div css={style} />
  );
}
```

However it's not working. This is the rendered HTML:

```
<div css="[object Object]" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the definitive change, but here's my config for an existing emotion project and I referenced these [Emotion docs](https://emotion.sh/docs/install#recommended-config) when setting it up

```js
// .babelrc.js file

env: {
    development: {
      presets: [
        "next/babel",
        [
          require.resolve('@emotion/babel-preset-css-prop'),
          {
            sourceMap: true,
            autoLabel: true,
          },
        ],
      ],
    },
    production: {
      presets: ["next/babel", [require.resolve('@emotion/babel-preset-css-prop'), { hoist: true }]],
    },
  },
```